# [42S22][1054] Unknown column in 'field list' error when trying calculation within select

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to transform the table

```
date        result
2005-05-09  win
2005-05-09  win
2005-05-09  loss
2005-05-09  loss
2005-05-10  win
2005-05-10  loss
2005-05-10  loss
```

into

```
date        win  loss
2005-05-09  2    2
2005-05-10  1    2
```

I find some way to do it like:

```
SELECT
  t.date,
  t.win,
  t.total - t.win AS loss
FROM (SELECT
        date,
        sum(if(result = "win", 1, 0)) AS win,
        count(*)                      AS total
      FROM matches
      GROUP BY date) t;
```

Yet my question is: *why I cannot do it without subquery?*, like this:

```
SELECT
        date,
        sum(if(result = "win", 1, 0)) AS win,
        count(*)                      AS total,
        total - win                   AS loss
      FROM matches
      GROUP BY date
```

This would give me an error:

```
[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'total' in 'field list'
```

I am using MySQL.

Comment: You cannot do it without a subquery because that is how SQL is defined:  you cannot use an alias defined in the `SELECT` statement in the rest of the `SELECT` statement or even in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I want to add:  I was going to vote to close this question.  But, there is no appropriate close reason.  And, I suspect that it is a question that many people wonder about.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the explanation. Very clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason why SQL does not allow aliases to be used in the `select` statement.

A `select` statement has a list of expressions.  The standard is quite explicit in *not* requiring any particular order of evaluation of the expressions.  That means that they are *not* necessarily evaluated in the order they are written.  Your query would generate incorrect results if `total` were calculated`before`win`.

To a large extent, this is to prevent any ambiguous interpretation of statements like this:

```
select x, y as x, x + 1
from x . . .
```

Which `x` does `x + 1` refer to?  In SQL the answer is clear:  the column `x` rather than the column `y`.

MySQL documentation is rather poor at explaining this.  The closest I can come is this excerpt ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)):

> In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

In fact, the rule is more general than what is stated:  the order of evaluation of any expression in the `select` is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (as Gordon pointed out in the comments) use an alias from the `SELECT` clause in other calculations in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` clauses. What you *can* do to avoid the subquery is to simply count the two values separately without intermediate values;

```
SELECT date, SUM(result='win') win, SUM(result='loss') loss
FROM matches
GROUP BY date
```

...or without MySQLism's;

```
SELECT date, COUNT(CASE WHEN result='win'  THEN 1 END) win,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN result='loss' THEN 1 END) loss
FROM matches
GROUP BY date;
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4334c/1).